# If $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ be two positive definite quadratic forms.Then the folowing must be a positive definite quadratic forms

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

If $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ be positive definite quadratic forms.
Then which of the folowings is a positive definite quadratic form?

1. $Q_1 + Q_2$
2. $Q_1 - Q_2$
3. $Q_1 \cdot Q_2$
4. $Q_1 / Q_2$

I think the first option is correct.

Comment: Which of them are actually quadratic forms?

Answer (score 2):

The first one $Q_1+Q_2$ will be again a positive definite quadratic form.

---

The second one;

- If we think of $Q_1-Q_2$ as $Q_1 \bot (-Q_2)$;
  then in this sense it is clearly an indefinite quadratic form.
  Note that $\left(Q_1 \bot (-Q_2) \right)(X_1, 0)=Q_1(X_1) > 0$;
  also 
  note that $\left(Q_1 \bot (-Q_2) \right)(0, X_2)=-Q_2(X_2) < 0$.

---

The third one; $Q_1 \cdot Q_2$ is not even a quadratic form 
(except the cases $Q_1 \equiv 0$ and $Q_2 \equiv 0$);
it is a $\color{Blue}{\text{quartic}}$ form.
Because for every arbitrary $\lambda$; we have:

$$ 
\left(Q_1 \cdot Q_2\right)(\lambda X_1,\lambda X_2) 
= 
Q_1 (\lambda X_1) \cdot Q_2(\lambda X_2) 
\\ 
= 
\left(\lambda ^2 \cdot Q_1(X_1)\right) 
\cdot 
\left(\lambda ^2 \cdot Q_2(X_2)\right) 
= 
\lambda ^4 \cdot Q_1(X_1) Q_2(X_2) 
= 
\lambda ^\color{Blue}{4} \left(Q_1 \cdot Q_2\right)( X_1, X_2) 
. 
$$

---

The last one $Q_1 / Q_2$ is not even a quadratic form 
(except the case $Q_1 \equiv 0$);
it will be a form of degree zero over the set 
$\{(X_1, X_2) : Q_2(X_2)\neq0\}$.
[In our special case 
$\{(X_1, X_2) : Q_2(X_2)\neq0\}= \{(X_1, X_2) : X_2\neq0 \}$ 
.]

Because for every arbitrary $\lambda$; we have:

$$ 
\left(\dfrac{Q_1} {Q_2}\right)(\lambda X_1,\lambda X_2) 
= 
\dfrac{Q_1 (\lambda X_1)} {Q_2(\lambda X_2)} 
\\ 
= 
\dfrac 
{\left(\lambda ^2 \cdot Q_1(X_1)\right)} 
{\left(\lambda ^2 \cdot Q_2(X_2)\right)} 
= 
\dfrac{Q_1(X_1)} {Q_2(X_2)} 
= 
\left(\dfrac{Q_1}{Q_2}\right)( X_1, X_2) 
. 
$$

Comment: If $Q_j(x,y)=j(x^2+y^2)$ ($j\in\{1,2\}$), then $Q_2-Q_1$ is a positive definite quadratic form.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos ; yes you are right; at first I think of $Q_1-Q_2$ as $Q_1 \bot (-Q_2)$; in this sense it is clearly an indefinite quadratic form.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos ; 
If we do not think of $Q_1-Q_2$; 
as $Q1 \bot (−Q2)$; 
***what choice do we have*** for $Q_1-Q_2$; 
in which we do not have any ***ambiguity***?  
For ***example*** let $Q_1(x,y)=2x^2+y^2$ and $Q_2(z)=2z^2$, 
also let $P(x)=2x^2$ and $P'(y)=2y^2$; 
I think anyone would agree with we, 
that $Q_2, P, P'$ give the same quadratic forms; 
but how should we define $Q_1-Q_2$.  
Should we consider $Q_1-Q_2$ as $Q_1-P=y^2$; (which is obviously definite)?  
Or 
should we consider $Q_1-Q_2$ as $Q_1-P'=2x^2-y^2$; (which is obviously in-definite)?

Comment: What about $(Q_2-Q_1)(x,y)=Q_2(x,y)-Q_1(x,y)=2(x^2+y^2)-(x^2+y^2)=x^2+y^2$?

Comment: @José Carlos Santos ; My question is : ***how should you define $Q_1-Q_2$*** for any arbitrary given quadratic forms; without any ***ambiguity***?

Comment: I don't see any ambiguity in defining $(Q_2-Q_1)(u)$ as $Q_2(u)-Q_1(u)$.